# UNIX - Setting string variable with other variables inside

Tags: string, bash, shell, unix, sed

I am having trouble setting my variables to the correct string in my UNIX shell script.  Here is my code ($1 is a filename):

```
nameIndex=$(echo "$lineCount+3" |bc);
name=$(sed -n -e "$nameIndexp" -e "$nameIndexq" $1);
echo "$name";
```

When $lineCount is 270, the output is just a new line.  That is, $name is not printed or not evaluated.

If $lineCount is 270, I want the output to be
`sed -n -e 273p -e 273q filename.txt`
which essentially prints the 273rd line of filename.txt

I appreciate your time!

Comment: `lineCount` is unlikely to be a floating-point value, so you can use `nameIndex=$(( lineCount + 3 ))` instead of calling the external `bc` program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$nameIndexp` and `$nameIndexq` look like unique variable names, so you need to use `${name}` syntax, i.e.

```
${nameIndex}p
```

and

```
${nameIndex}q
```

to separate the variable name from the plain text.

```
nameIndex=$(echo "$lineCount+3" |bc)
name=$(sed -n -e "${nameIndex}p" -e "${nameIndex}q" $1)
echo "$name"
```

Comment: Its better to not use back tics.  Not sure why you have changed the original parentheses one one line to back ticks and not the other. Use: `nameIndex=$(echo "$lineCount+3" |bc)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do math in `bash` without using `bc` like this:

```
nameIndex=$(($lineCount+3))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
nameIndex=`echo "$lineCount+3" |bc`
par=$1
name=$(sed -n -e "$nameIndexp" -e "$nameIndexq" $par)
echo "$name"
```

Comment: its same as question `kfsone` is right `"${nameIndex}p"` is better approach